# Facebook Graph API - Get list of id's and names that have liked a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook Graph API, how do I get the list of people who have liked a specific item (say a post)? Doing a call like `/ITEM_ID/?fields=likes` using the Graph Explorer I'm able to see a list of names in the `[data]` array, but, when I call it from a website it doesn't display the names, it just shows the `count` value.

I'm thinking it's one of two things, but I'm not sure:

1. I'm using the wrong access token. I'm using the extended one for the fan page the post is on.
2. Facebook just doesn't give out that info to someone (or a fan page) that isn't the owner of the original post. (I'm the one who made the post.)

Is there a way to get the list of user names and user id's that have liked a post, and if so, what's required to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be 2 reasons-

1. You access token is not correct. You need the `read_stream` permission for getting the posts.
2. You are not parsing the resulted JSON correctly.

Comment: According to the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) on the Facebook Developers website, the access token being used does have `read_stream` permissions. And, I can read the JSON un-parsed and see that the names and ids of the people who have liked the post aren't in there, so parsing isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

/ITEM_ID?fields=likes.fields(id,name)
i have done this like this ( me/feed?fields=likes.fields(id,name) ) and it works